# Creating dynamic chart titles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dynamic, chart, title

Is it possible to dynamically generate a chart title based on a source feature class attribute value?

Specifically, I am generating a series of cross-sections using an existing polyline f.c. ("XS_2009BEBrklnTerr_interpZ") and the "Create Profile Tool" from 3D analyst.  Sample below:

[image: Example of Cross Section]

I would like:

1. the Profile Graph Title to populate automatically from the [SegID] field (data type = double)
2. the Profile Graph Subtitle to populate automatically from the [Station] field (data type = double).

Note: line geometry and attributes are contained in the same f.c. in a file geodatabase (Arc 10.0, SP4).

I have tried the following (unsuccessfully) by typing into the text portion of the chart's "Advanced Properties":
- writing as if a label expression (e.g."Segment " & [SegID])
- writing as dynamic text for Data Driven Pages: `Segment:<dyn type="title" property="SegID"/>`

---

I was unable to figure out within Arc, so I dived into Python.  It's a lot more complicated than I'd anticipated, but I think I'm on the right track.  I believe my problem now is in using the 3D feature geometry as the input data axes...I will post in a separate question.

Comment: There are a lot of individual questions here, and it would be best if you stuck to one or two similar questions per post. It's easier to answer that way.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've trimmed accordingly.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

An edit that the asker made to their question indicates that they decided to approach their requirement differently:

> I was unable to figure out within Arc, so I dived into Python. It's a
>   lot more complicated than I'd anticipated, but I think I'm on the
>   right track. I believe my problem now is in using the 3D feature
>   geometry as the input data axes...I will post in a separate question.

The separate question mentioned above seems to be [Using Z and M feature geometry to create line graph in ArcPy/Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102369/using-z-and-m-feature-geometry-to-create-line-graph-in-python).